# Java - Given an int array print true if it contains 2 or 3

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Im dooing a java1001 course, so we are not doing object oriented programming. I'm having trouble figuring out this problem regarding an array.

Given an int array, print true if it contains a 2 or a 3. //
       {2, 5} -> true                                          //
       {4, 3} -> true                                          //
       {4, 5} -> false                                         //

```
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int size = keyboard.nextInt();
  int[] a = new int[size];

  for(int i = 0 ;i<a.length;i++)
    a[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

  for(int i = 0 ;i<a.length;i++)

    if(a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3)
    System.out.println(true);

    else
    System.out.println(false);
```

When tested it yields "truefalse", "falsetrue" and "falsefalse"
How can I make it stop examining the entire array if the first integer yields true ?

Any one that can help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should figure that out by yourself. As soon as you meet 2 or 3, you can stop looping and print true. But if you meet some other number, you can't print false until you've reached the end of the loop. Use a variable to hold the result and print the result when finished.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Debug Problem"

Comment: `if(<<found something>>){return;};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by using the `break` keyword, although this *won't* fix your issue.

```
 if(a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3) {
     System.out.println(true);
     break;
 }
```

**What does break do?**

Break simply stops what it's doing in a loop. If you're cycling through a `for loop` and you don't need to cycle any more, use the `break` keyword, and it will stop the loop.

**How will it work in this instance?**

As soon as your loop hits a `2` or a `3`, it's going to print out `true`. It will then hit the `break`, and the loop ends.

If it hits anyhting else, it will move to the `else`, and print `false`. This, however, is not desired, so we're going to do it a little differently. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
boolean b = false;

for( i from 0 to size)
{
    if this is a 2 or a 3
       b = true;
       break;
}

// Print the result.
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: That won't fix the algorithm. It will still print falsetrue.

Comment: dont forget about brackets :)

Comment: Take a look at my edit, plus the pseudocode.

Comment: I've removed the downvote. But you should reword the beginning, because it still reads it as "just do that", although that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`How can I make it stop examining the entire array if the first integer yields true?`
If you want to check the first integer in the array alone, you can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; I < a.length; i++)
    if(a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3)
    {
        System.out.println(true);
        break;
    }

if (i == a.length)
    System.out.println(false);
```

You can even fit your entire code into a single loop for better performance, at least theoretically.
Consider:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = keyboard.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[size];

int pos = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    a[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(pos != -1)
    {
        if((a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3) && )
        {
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

if(pos == -1)
{
    System.out.println(false);
}
else
{
    System.out.println(true + " (index = " + pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boolean` to check if the array contains *2* or *3*, Ex:

```
boolean isFound = false;
for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length && !isFound; i++) {
    isFound = a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3;
}
System.out.println(isFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int tam = a.length;
for(int i = 0 ;i<tam;i++)
   if(a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3)
   {
      System.out.println(true);
      tam = -1;
   }
   else if (tam == a.length)
      System.out.println(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that below things will help you

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = keyboard.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[size];
boolean flag = false;

for(int i = 0 ;i<a.length;i++)
a[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

for(int i = 0 ;i<a.length;i++)

if(a[i] == 2 || a[i] == 3){
flag = true;
break;
}

if(flag)
System.out.println("True");
else
System.out.println("False");
```